# Know the number of record of the previous activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, node.js, custom-activity

I'm developping a custom activity for Journey Builder and I would like to know if there is a way during the execution to know the number of record that was in the previous activity. For example : you have a wait 1day and then your activity, is it possible to know, how much contacts are stuck in the wait or have been sticked ?